# Has there ever been a space hotel in the Star Wars universe?

Tags: star-wars

I would love if they built a hotel orbiting the planet in space. However, I wonder. Since space travel is so commonplace in Star Wars, **has there ever been a case where the denizens of the galaxy have constructed a space hotel?**

Comment: Does [real life](http://www.holidayguru.ie/travel-magazine/star-wars-hotels/) count? :-P

Comment: Do you mean a hotel floating in space?  Or a hotel on some planet?

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Alderaanian_flying_hotel

Comment: Also the hotels on Manaan

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Royal_K_Hotel_and_Casino

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Gravane_station

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Toryaz_Station

Comment: http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Darknon_Station

Comment: you mean in "outer" space? Otherwise, Cloud City would be a solid canon example

Answer (score 1):

Well, there was the Space Station the "Paradise" - which was basically a den - temporary living station - haven for gambling, crime, bounty hunters and all around bad dudes (referenced in Darth Bane: Dynasty of Evil. Was located on the Corellian Trade Spine).

Comment: Can you provide any quotes from the book to support your answer?

Answer (score 1):

I know in the book The Crystal Star-Legends-There is Creish(spelling) station. It sat on the edge of a white dwarf. There were hotel rooms-along with a med area with stations to use medication, a casino for those wanting to gamble, and restaurants serving food Mall FoodCourt Style. Chewbacca ate something called Won-Tons(granite like slugs). Han gambled and won cash playing a Chance card game. There was also the area where the plot revolved around-an altar/religious area.